# Is there any guide or organisation solution for increasing utilization of laboratory and lab equipment?

Tags: research-process, lab-management, facilities-services

We obtained a report for the last academic year. A shocking revelation was that the capacity utilization* of lab equipment, laboratories, instruments and machines is only 37%. Everyone seems to be happy with this result, most of the comments are that science can't be lucrative and researchers cannot be forced to work with already existing equipment. If they want to expand research and buy a new machine (even if we have 3 already) that should be allowed. "Your grant your rules".

Is there any organization method to overcome this "abeyance" of overall facilities at faculty?

*Utilization was calculated by time and resources being used, versus number of publications and number of employees (students, professors, researchers).

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. Your complaint is that some equipment is not utilized as much as you think it should be, and nobody but you thinks this is a problem? Why do *you* think it's a problem?

Comment: no, @ff524 I asked if there is any organisational design to improve utilisation of faculty research resources. This recourses are equipment, lab materials and instruments, machines and area in whole. I think it is a problem, if you have something that you don't use frequently, costs of repair and maintenance are higher than sending sample outside of institution, (example, sequencer, running cost more than sending sample to specialized company )

Comment: If you have data showing that the costs of keeping the equipment in-house (at its current level of utilization) are higher than sending samples out, I assume you must have showed that data to those who find the status quo acceptable. What was their response? You should [edit] all this information (including the last sentence of your comment) into your question, as it's likely to be highly relevant to any answer you might get.

Comment: I think it would be outside of scope of my question? I was referring to known management and organisational methods for scientific or/and educational institutions. I think 37 is not satisfactory, do you think that I am creating a problem by raising this question?

Comment: Your question is fine. I'm also interested in strategies to increase lab efficiency.

Comment: I agree with @ff524 that this question would be *much* easier and better to answer if you gave more evidence about why you think 37% "utilization" is too low. 37% is just a number - it can be great, terrible, or just usual utilization. Equipment usage depends on many things including (a) whether the machines you have are sufficient for the planned research, (b) how allocation policies etc. currently work, (c) whether the equipment is general-purpose or extremely specific, (d) to what extend your institution is even allowed to use hardware bought with a specific grant in other contexts, etc.

Comment: I think my reasons are not factual, @xLeitix rather feeling that faculty is poorly managed and capacities are not used enough. I acknowledge that everyone have their own right to plan and design research as they want, although I think it is strange to design in a way that dont correspond with available methods, (b) allocation policies are pretty simple, except if some machines are in personal ownership of professors, they will usually ask for co-authorship (c) both (d) good question, I dont know,

Comment: A work week is somewhere around 40 hours, a full week (24/7) is $7 \cdot 24 =  168$ hours. This would make 23%. I'd say 37% is stellar...

Comment: I thought I understood what the 37% represented, *until* I read the part about "versus number of publications and number of employees (students, professors, researchers)." Perhaps you could better clarify how "number of publications and number of employees" was used in this calculation?

Comment: so percent of utilisation decreases if you have low number of publication and high number of employees. @DanielR.Collins if surface area ( prescribed by accreditation institution is 8 square m per student and employee) and utilization of this area is not utilised in timely and proper organisation timeframe, percent increase, this is also utilised for other categories-utilisation of machines, materials, equipment, dishes. and average of each individual value is made..and you get finale score.cumulative average of each individual features important for productivity of institution

Comment: It's extremely hard to understand what you're saying. There seems to be some calculation where if the equipment is used constantly around-the-clock, but no papers are being published, then this would count as 0% "utilization"?

Comment: @SSimon Could you please add a link to *A shocking revelation... 37%*?

Comment: Are you using the term "capacity utilization" in the sense that's defined [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacity_utilization)?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins yes!" if there wasn't any educational activities, and if no paper is published than in that scenario it would be 0%, why is that strange?

Comment: yes @chipbuster

Comment: It's strange because it can be "used" 100% but "utilized" 0% at the same time; but those words mean the same thing in everyday English usage. Perhaps it would be helpful if you put an *exact formula* for this calculation, or link to same, in your question.

Comment: you never heard about capacity utilization @DanielR.Collins ? It can be positive ( yield with success ) and negative, where no results are obtained

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, the 37% capacity utilization number is essentially meaningless on its own, because it does not directly relate to the actual metric that one might wish to optimize.

When attempting to improve efficiency, it's important to have a precise understanding of what the ultimate metric is that it being maximized.  In a university research setting, the metric being maximized is *not* utilization of equipment, but rather something regarding research being accomplished and effective use of grant money.  To maximize such metrics, it's actually *important* that some equipment be idle some fraction of the time.

The problem is, research projects typically have highly uneven and unpredictable resource utilization profiles.  For example, my collaborators will often have 1-2 day bursts of flow cytometer use, in which they use a $200K machine for an hour or so every few hours, followed by a weeks-long gap while they prepare the next experiment.  It's very difficult to interleave usage during such bursts without distorting somebody's experimental plans, and an experiment may need to be started several days before the flow cytometer is first run.  Counterintuitively, this means that *overall experimental efficiency demands that flow cytometers stand idle most of the time*.

An even more extreme example is common tools like pipettes or screwdrivers: if anyone ever needs to spend more than a few seconds looking for such a tool, then operations are clearly inefficient.  As a professor of mine once told me: "If you can't just reach out and pick up the screwdriver you need, you don't have enough screwdrivers."  This means that such common tools must have exceedingly low capacity utilization in order to used efficiently as part of the larger workflow.

That same professor, on the other hand, now runs an operation in which an automated high-throughput mass spectrometer is carefully scheduled to run 24 hours a day, since it is the key high-value bottleneck of an entire pipeline.  In that case, efficiency means 100% utilization (but also that when they have grown enough, they will probably add another mass spectrometer).

Bottom line: if you want to improve efficiency, knowing the utilization of equipment is a useful starting point, but it can only be properly interpreted in terms of the larger workflow in which that equipment is used.

Comment: but what if your lab start to aloud others departments and faculties(unies) to use your flow cytometer? That would increase utilisation ?

Comment: research plus educational setting

Comment: @SSimon What you describe is essentially flow cytometry as part of core facilities.  My collaborators have bought their own flow cytometers because sharing the equipment meant their research was significantly inhibited by the wait times and competition for equipment.  Yes, there is still sharing (i.e., they will let other labs they trust use it when nobody in their lab wants it), but 100% utilization is highly suboptimal with this particular type of equipment, as it is for most.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd like to add that in the labs where I work, we also rather typically have spatial constraints as well. We operate three instruments in one small lab, of which two need to have the room dark for the actual measurement. Also, if you have many people operating systems in a way where the experiments mean that actual beamlines are configured differently, essentially everyone needs to go through a full configuration, alignment and calibration procedure for their experiments. Thus, it is more efficient to reserve blocks of time in case the experiments don't go as smooth as hoped.

Comment: I think it is important to realize that the costs of not being able to work well is often much more expensive than the instruments. Plus, many instruments wear out rather by abuse and working hours than by standing around unused.

Comment: yes @cbeleites can you back up with some sources your claims?

Comment: @SSimon: Example 1: One of our students just redid 4 days of experiments because he hadn't realized that one of the shared pipettes he used was not working correctly. A PhD student here in Germany has marginal costs of around 100 - 150 EUR per working day. 4 days equal 2 - 3 new pipettes. Agreed, the student should have checked the pipette before using it. But for shared pipettes, the respective student would need to check it pretty much before every experiment, for your "own" pipettes you know when you need to service them (regularly or because something bad happened). Commercial pipette ...

Comment: ... check comes at around 50 EUR. The student can do it, but needs to go another lab for the balance. I don't know exactly, but I'd guess that you don't do it properly below 2 - 3 h for the set of pipettes (all preparations included). Say, over the year 40 h, i.e. one work week can be saved by having "own" set of pipettes for a student who works quantitatively. That is roughly a set of 3 pipettes per year. And this does not include figure in the annoyance it causes if you always need to spend major amounts of time before you can start the "real" experiment.

Answer (score 3):

Take my advice - invest in human hamster wheels to generate lab electricity, rather than buying it off the grid. So long as you make sure the wheels aren't **too** efficient, it should be possible to get most if not all of your researchers utilizing the equipment, 24hrs a day, 7 days a week. You may see a slight dip in the utilization of other lab equipment, but the high usage in both number and duration of use of hamster wheels should pull up the whole departmental average.

[image]

I am, of course, being facetious. A lab is not a factory that turns some arbitrary raw material into widgets en masse. Time and motion principles of labour management simply do not apply. If anything you want scientists using equipment **less** for the same amount of science published. In all seriousness, the only real machine whos utilization is worth tracking would be the coffee machine.

Lab efficiency however is a different ball game. Labs can be more or less efficient, however thats a different question for a different post :)

Comment: why you think lab is not a factory? It is factory of research articles. How many papers are published and in what journal are published tells directly about lab performance and without good utilisation you cannot have optimal number of publications

Comment: Unfortunately we have a difference of opinion about this, so i'm not going to be much help going forward. Perhaps one thing we could agree on is that old, unused hardware isn't doing anyone any favours.
One idea would be to donate it to Seeding Labs: http://seedinglabs.org/
Dumping your underutilized stock will improve ratings, plus you can pop some blurb into the website about how U. of Z is doing its bit. Most importantly, I think you are one of the few people who would be indifferent enough to the scientist's pro-hoarding protests that you might actually be able to get the job done :)

Comment: I understand you @J.J unfortunately, I think your vision of research and institutions in modern world, are not in touch with reality and current historical modern of developing research. " Researchers are not talented, rather gifted for organisation and planning"

Answer (score 2):

The U.S. Department of Energy has a system of user facilities.  Access to these facilities requires an application and scheduling.  Access is typically free.  At least some of these facilities reach 100% utilization.  Each tool in each facility may have its own rules.  These are often listed on websites.  Facilities are incentivized to reach their utilization targets with funding.

Example:  http://www.anl.gov/cnm/user-information/user-access-program

Answer (score 2):

To complement earlier responses, two types of cost come into play:

1. context-switching (when you have to go to a different department to use the tool) or re-calibrate whatever tool you use every time you take it from the joint pool;
2. unpredictability due to use fluctuation. It is known from queuing theory that with queue use approaching full (theoretical) capacity the fluctuations grow significantly. Sometimes not being able to estimate whether a tool will be free to use can hamper your productivity more than the cost of the tool. There is a reason why a rigid scheduling regime is implemented only for really expensive devices.

So, 37% may represent a perfectly good balance for these costs and as measure of utilisation it is not sufficiently informative in isolation.

Comment: yes, @Captain waist majority of stuff at my inst share your point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you're looking into increasing your resource utilization you might want to check out [Clustermarket](https://www.clustermarket.com/) - they offer sharing your equipment externally and gaining an additional income which is always an added bonus. They also have a white paper about resource utilisation that could be useful.